# What is a quick ssh command to know the system info/configuration

Tags: configuration, ssh, system

Ive been googling for quite some while and couldn't find it! I need to know the specs of our hosting server system. And also this command will be quite useful in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

there are various tools you can use depending on the OS distribution. eg `uname -a`, `lspci`, `lshw` , `dmesg`, `biosdecode` etc .

Comment: Cool thanks, kinda what i was looking for. Thanks for the other options.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the uname command: ([man uname](http://www.rdg.ac.uk:8081/cgi-bin/cgiwrap/wsi14/poplog/man/1/uname))

Example: `$uname -a`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like `ssh $HOSTNAME uname -a`?

Comment: Yea, but not quite. Anything that gives more info? This is the output:

Linux mail.xxxxxxx.com 2.4.27-grsec.EIS1 #2 Tue Aug 24 21:41:55 CDT 2004 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Thats probably enough to know what packages you need to install based on system requirements. I'm not sure. But thanks for your suggestion.